# load all databases from the source to ADLG2(azure data lake gen2)

Tags: sql-server, database, azure, azure-data-lake-gen2

is there a way to load all databases from the source SQL Server to the data lake as it is?

I tried to load each database with his tables but I am asking if there was a way to load all databases as it is to the data lake

Comment: Please share what you have tried and what error if you are facing any? and your source data base is on-premises or Azure SQL?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**One of the ways to load all databases from SQL to ADLG2 is by using `Azure Data Factory`**

Follow the below procedure to load all databases from SQL to ADLG2:

1. First create one pipeline and take script activity in it **add linked service with master database** select script as `Query` And give the following query:

```sql
    SELECT name, database_id, create_date  
    FROM sys.databases;
```

[image]

2. Then take `ForEach` activity and int its settings give Items as so it will fetch output of script activity

```
    @activity('Script1').output.resultSets[0].rows
```

[image]

3. In for each activity take one `lookup` activity, create and add linked service for database with dynamic values

[image]

In that dataset add Db name parameter

[image]

Noe send this parameter  value to linked service properties as below

[image]

Lookup activity settings

```sql
SELECT table_Schema, TABLE_NAME, TABLE_CATALOG
FROM information_Schema.tables
WHERE TABLE_TYPE =  'BASE TABLE'sql
```

[image]

4. now take execute pipeline activity click on new in that pipeline create `lookupOP` parameter with `array` datatype and in execute pipeline pass the value to it as output of lookup as `@activity('Lookup1').output.value`

[image]

[image]

5. In that new pipeline take `ForEach` activity and passthe parameter we created as items

[image]

6. In that for each activity take one copy activity and for the source dataset create linked service on SQL database with dynamic values as we created previously

[image]

In this dataset create parameters for database name, table name and schema name

[image]

now add these dynamic values to linked service properties and Table name, table schema

[image]

Copy activity source setting:

[image]

create parameters in sink dataset

[image]

now add these dynamic values to folder name, file name

[image]

Copy activity Sink settings

[image]

**Output**

creating folder of database name and in that folder loading tables of that particular database

[image]